# Strategy for programmatically verifying javascripts are up to date

Tags: javascript, html, versioning

Besides versioning numbers in querystring parameters for the css and js files, are there any good strategies for handling old cached script files from code?

I guess the simplest solution would be a try catch in the page calling scripts in each script file returning version numbers and ensuring they are the expected version.

Is there a better strategy?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grunt-usemin`, for revisioning of the assets.

https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin

It uses `grunt-rev` under the hood, which provides changes for revisions of files only if file content is changed. This way you can cache all of the JS files, and make sure that html file itself isn't cached, so it will see the updates in script tag itself.

But this will only work if you'll use grunt for preprocessing of original html.

Comment: Basic scaffold for `yeoman` tool is a great example how it works in practice.